# change child components' state from parent (exclusive clickable box component with React)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am writing a Box component which

- shows a div box
- the box's CSS style needs to be different when the mouse pointer is on / off the component
- when I click on the box then its style must change to indicate that it is turned on

I wrote this component and it works fine.

Now I would like to improve my component. I need to show multiply Box on my parent page and when I click on one Box I would like to reset the state of the rest Box components displays on parent so when I move mouse between the Boxes their styles need to be change and when I click one of them then the selected Box's border needs to be change.

**This is the Box component:**

```
const STYLE = {
  boxMouseOver: {...},
  boxMouseOut: {...},
  boxOn: {...},
}

export default class ClickableBox extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      mouseOver: false,
      turnOn: false
    }
  }

  handleMouseOver = () => {
    this.setState({
      mouseOver: true
    })
  }

  handleMouseOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      mouseOver: false
    })
  }

  handleOnClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      turnOn: !this.state.turnOn
    });

    this.props.resetStateCallback();
  }

  resetState = () = => {
    this.setState({
      turnOn: false
    });
  }

  render () {
    let style = this.state.mouseOver ? STYLE.boxMouseOver : STYLE.boxMouseOut
    style = this.state.turnOn ? STYLE.boxOn : style

    return (
      <div style={style} onMouseOver={this.handleMouseOver} onMouseOut={this.handleMouseOut} onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
        <span style={STYLE.title}>{this.props.title}</span>
        <br/>{this.state.turnOn ? "on" : "off"}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**And this is the parent component:**

```
export default class GroupOfBoxes extends React.Component {
  reset () {
    alert('reset')

    // **** I need help for this part ****
    // Need to be called resetState() method on
    // ClickableBox components shows on this page
    for (currentBox : ?????) {
       if (currentBox != selected Box??) {
          currentBox.resetState()
       }
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid>
          <Row className='show-grid'>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <ClickableBox title='1' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='2' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='3' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='4' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row className='show-grid'>
            <Col sm={12}>
              <ClickableBox title='5' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='6' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='7' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
              <ClickableBox title='8' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I do not know hot to change the Box component state from the parent page because I need to have references of my Box components on the parent page and call `ClickableBox.resetState()` method on each `ClickableBox` components from the `GroupOfBoxes.reset()` method.

**---- UPDATE ----**

After I read more React related docs I was able to make my code works but I think that my solution is far from the optimal. I would appreciate any help for optimalisation.

So I use `ref` property to get references to the my Box components and I wrote lots of conditions to decide which Box components need to be reset:

**First, I made change on the ClickableBox component, I added a 'this' param to the resetStateCallback method call:**

```
handleOnClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    turnOn: !this.state.turnOn
  });

  this.props.resetStateCallback(this);
}
```

**Then I added the ref keys to the parent component:**

```
<ClickableBox ref='box1' title='1' body='...' footer='...' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
<ClickableBox ref='box2' title='2' body='...' footer='...' resetStateCallback={this.reset} />
...
```

**Finally I modified the reset() method on parent component:**

(this method looks so ugly so please help me to optimalize it if you can)

```
reset(comp) {
  if (comp.props.title === '1') {
    this.refs.box2.resetState()
    this.refs.box3.resetState()
    this.refs.box4.resetState()
    this.refs.box5.resetState()
    this.refs.box6.resetState()
    this.refs.box7.resetState()
    this.refs.box8.resetState()
  } else if (comp.props.title === '2') {
    this.refs.box1.resetState()
    this.refs.box3.resetState()
    this.refs.box4.resetState()
    this.refs.box5.resetState()
    this.refs.box6.resetState()
    this.refs.box7.resetState()
    this.refs.box8.resetState()
  } else if (comp.props.title === '3') {
    this.refs.box1.resetState()
    this.refs.box2.resetState()
    this.refs.box4.resetState()
    this.refs.box5.resetState()
    this.refs.box6.resetState()
    this.refs.box7.resetState()
    this.refs.box8.resetState()
  } else if (comp.props.title === '4') {
    ...
  } else if (comp.props.title === '5') {
    ...
  } else if (comp.props.title === '6') {
    ...
  } else if (comp.props.title === '7') {
    ...
  } else if (comp.props.title === '8') {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: trying to understand this a bit better. Is the idea that when you click one box, all the other boxes states reset? You could potentially move the state to the parent, make `Box` receive props instead?

Comment: That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap all the boxes inside `BoxWrapper`. BoxWrapper has two properties in its state: `mouseOverIndex` and `clickedIndex`.

It passes this state down to its children. That way, all the logic is held in the wrapper, and `Box` does not need to know of the state of its siblings.

See https://jsfiddle.net/20kpgjcj/3/